# How to play huge WEBM file Locally

Tags: javascript, media-source, web-mediarecorder

I am working with `Mediarecorder` to record video. I need to show LOCAL preview of this video directly from the browser. My problem is long time recordings and huge sized videos. So i can't store MediaRecorder blobs in memory, because it will lead to browser crush on machines with low memory (RAM). So each webm blob from `onDataAvailable` i store into `indexedDB`. 
After finishing recording i request all stored data from `indexedDB` by `getAll` transaction, but i still have same problem with memory. How can i play this array of blobs without loading all data into memory? How can i buffer this data?

I try to use `MediaSource API`

My method to get data from `indexedDB`:

```
function getAllData(indexedDB){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
           var transaction = indexedDB.transaction(["blobs"], 'readonly');
           var dbResult = transaction.objectStore("blobs").getAll();

           dbResult.onerror = function (error) {
               reject('failed to read from db: ' + error);
           }

           dbResult.onsuccess = function (event) {
               resolve(event.target.result);
           }
       }); 
    }
```

And when trying to play by `MediaSource API`:

```
getAllData().then(function (chunks) {

   var mediaSource = new MediaSource();
   var sourceBuffer;

   var player = document.createElement('video');
   var previewContainer = document.getElementById('preview_container');

   player.width = 300;
   player.height = 200;
   player.autoPlay = false;
   player.controls = true;

   player.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);

   mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', function (e) {
      sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/webm; codecs="vp8"');

      (function readCunks(index) {
          var fileReader = new FileReader();
          index = index || 0;

          if (index >= chunks.length) {
              return;
          }

          fileReader.onload = function (e) {
              sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(new Uint8Array(e.target.result)); 
              readCunks(++index);
          };

          fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(chunks[index]);
        })();
    }, false);

    previewContainer.innerHTML = "";
    previewContainer.appendChild(preview.player);
    player.play();
}).catch(function (e) {
     console.log('error on get data from db: ' + e);
});
```

But i get error `"Failed to execute 'appendBuffer' on 'SourceBuffer': This SourceBuffer has been removed from the parent media source."`

Update:
In addition i tested this code on Firefox. Is partially worked... After adding chunk 100 to `sourseBuffer` i got error: `QuotaExceededError`

So i have two main questions:

1. How can i fix SourceBuffer error and why it happens?
2. This is the best way to store and play huge .webm files Locally?

Comment: Do you, at some point, need to merge these chunks into a single big file, in the browser ? If not, use multiple MediaRecorders. When reaching limit duration, finalize current chunk as a standalone video, that you'll store in indexedDB (as binary) and start a new recorder. Then it's quite easy to treat all these chunks as if they were a single video. And for *1*, I would say that as long as you didn't merged the chunks from `MediaRecorder.ondataavailable.data`, these Blobs don't really represent chunks of the final video, hence the inability of MSE to play it, but I'm not sure about it...

Comment: Hi Kaiido. I tried this way. My limit is 2 hours of recording. Using mediaRecorder without fetching data of two hours lead to browsers crush and performance problems on weak machines. For example i3 with 4GB of ram.Maybe i don't understand correctly your solution

Comment: Yeah, I can guess that 2 hours of raw video is hard to maintain in memory ;-) Even professional video editing tools don't keep all that data in memory, but MediaRecorder needs to keep everything fresh as long as you didn't stopped the recorder. Try to lower this limit to few minutes only.

Comment: My problem is not MediaRecorder. The mediaRecorder onDataAvalible event fired each 5 seconds, and data chunk is stored directly to indexDB store (this is not memory), so i can record more when 2 hours :) But i still have a problem to play this data on HTML5 video element

Comment: No you don't get it, even if you do store chunks elsewhere than in live memory, the browsers also do store these recorded chunks in memory as long as the recorder is live. Create new MediaRecorders.

Comment: And also, why are you requesting all the indexedDB stored chunks at once if you are using MSE ? Feed the MediaSource only when required

Comment: I supporting two browsers: Firefox and Chrome. I need to play whole file stored by chunks on indexedDB, what you mean request if needed? Can you post your solution please?

Comment: I unfortunately don't have time right now, but I'll come back in few days if you still didn't figured it out